# Can I steal a permanent indefinitely with Frenzied Fugue?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Frenzied Fugue](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFrenzied%20Fugue%5d) says this:

> Enchantment — Aura
>
> Enchant permanent
>
> When Frenzied Fugue enters the battlefield or at the beginning of your
>   upkeep, gain control of enchanted permanent until end of turn. Untap
>   that permanent. It gains haste until end of turn.

If I enchant a permanent controled by my opponent, then make the [Frenzied Fugue](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFrenzied%20Fugue%5d) leave the battlefield (by sacrificing it, destroying, etc.), do I lose the control of the permanent at the end of the turn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "until end of turn" effect lasts until the end of the turn, regardless of whether or not Frenzied Fugue remains on the battlefield.

> 611.2a A continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability lasts as long as stated by the spell or ability creating it (such as “until end of turn”). If no duration is stated, it lasts until the end of the game.

If the effect read "[...] until end of turn or until Frenzied Fugue leaves the battlefield.", then you would lose control as soon as Frenzied Fugue left the battlefield.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. The solution to keep the permanent seems to be [mtg:Synod Sanctum].

Comment: Funnily enough, someone has asked for a list of cards that permanently take control on this site. https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/28196/6692

Comment: @liberforce If you're trying to abuse mutiny-style effects, try flicker cards. Most of them are in white or blue, but there's also stuff like Conjurer's Closet. (Of course, Frenzied Fugue by itself will let you borrow a creature "half-time" anyway.)